# Adding MFA to C# MVC app built on custom authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-factor-authentication

I have an old ASP .NET app which uses MVC as front end but utilizes a WCF service layer underneath for business logic and authentication. The controllers for the MVC app call into Models which underneath talk to this wcf service. This WCF service talks to the DB for authentication and all calls to the DB happen through this layer.

Now I need to add MFA to this app and I am lost as to what I can use out of the box to make this happen without having to move to Identity/OWIN and having to totally change the application architecture.

I am looking for pointers to how I can get a minimal sms/email token based second factor authentication on top of my existing userid/password authentication done using the wcf service.

Thanks

Comment: You just want to do multi factor authentication on the client? Then you only need to secure the endpoints the client talks to, probably your MVC front end.

Comment: When the client hits the login controller, I want to check the authentication using WCF ( which si what the application does currently) and then provide them with a text box/widget which asks them to enter the code ( which may come from SMS or an email ) .    All  the examples I see use Identity or OWIN being used to create the tokens, send them to the client via either SMS or email.  I want to see if there is a library which can help with the token management and me not having to write the code myself.

Comment: Okay. So now I'm not clear on what you're stuck on. It sounds like you have a clear idea of what to do and just now need to go implement the code.

Comment: What I don't want to write is

1. Implement RFCs for TOTP etc
2.All registration code

Any libraries out there where I can forklift the code and then write the glue myself?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is not [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Libraries can easily be found with you favorite search engine. Did you try a basic search for "C# mvc multi factor authentication"?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and most of the examples are using Identity/OWIN framework.  I am now looking Authy as they have a REST API that I can use and not have to generate or manage the tokens. 

Need to see if they support sending tokens to email as in my limited research, they support  AuthyApp, SMS and Voice only.